# Creating a element using gmail.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

I am now working on a chrome extension using gmail.js APIs.

According to the [tutorial](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/tree/master#gmaildomemailemail_el-or-email_id), the function should receive a parameter when being called(namely, `email_id` or **email element**). But when I passed a email_id to the function, I got an error message like this: **"api.dom.email called with invalid element/id"**.

[image]

As you can see in the screen shot above, I could even run `gmail.get.email_id()` well, but it did not work when calling `gmail.dom.email(gmail.get.email_id())`.

Comment: We developed an in-house tool, and ours broke with the same error near the same time as your post.

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix for this was sent in as a PR by Github user [Brent Kelley](https://github.com/brentkelly) in this [Pull Request](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/pull/256)